# How can I make an editor dirty in eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, rcp

```
`public class ApplicationActionBarAdvisor extends ActionBarAdvisor {

    private IWorkbenchAction saveAction;
    private IWorkbenchAction saveAllAction;

    // Actions - important to allocate these only in makeActions, and then use
    // them
    // in the fill methods. This ensures that the actions aren't recreated
    // when fillActionBars is called with FILL_PROXY.

    public ApplicationActionBarAdvisor(IActionBarConfigurer configurer) {
        super(configurer);
    }
     protected void makeActions(final IWorkbenchWindow window) {
         saveAction = ActionFactory.SAVE.create(window);
        register(saveAction);

        saveAllAction = ActionFactory.SAVE_ALL.create(window);
        register(saveAllAction);
        }

//      protected void fillMenuBar(IMenuManager menuBar) {
//      }

        protected void fillCoolBar(ICoolBarManager coolBar) {
            IToolBarManager saveToolbar = new ToolBarManager(SWT.FLAT | SWT.RIGHT);
            saveToolbar.add(saveAction);
            saveToolbar.add(saveAllAction);
            coolBar.add(new ToolBarContributionItem(saveToolbar, "save"));
        }

package rcp_application;

import org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelection;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IStructuredSelection;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow;
import org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException;
import org.eclipse.ui.handlers.HandlerUtil;

public class CallEditor extends AbstractHandler {

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event);
        IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
        BottomView view = (BottomView)page.findView(BottomView.ID);

        ISelection selection = view.getSite().getSelectionProvider()
                .getSelection();

        if (selection != null && selection instanceof IStructuredSelection) {
            Object obj = ((IStructuredSelection) selection).getFirstElement();
            if (obj != null) {
                Person person = (Person) obj;
                MyEditorInput input = new MyEditorInput(person);
                try {
                  page.openEditor(input, MyEditor.ID);

                } catch (PartInitException e) {
                  throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
              }
            }
        return null;
    }

}`
```

I have tried many ways to make an editor dirty in RCP but non worked. I am implementing IEditorPart for my editor. When I edit the contents of editor it does not get marked dirty and save button remains disable. But when I click on view then Save become active. I'm calling firePropertyChange() but when I debug my program and step into firePropertyChange() the list of listeners found null. Anyone have the solution please do share. Thanks.

Comment: Are you implementing `IEditorPart` directly or extending `EditorPart`?

Comment: @greg-449 I'm extending EditorPart

Comment: @greg-449 I'm calling firePropertyChange() but when I debug my program and step into firePropertyChange() the list of listeners found null.

Comment: If the listeners list is empty it may be that the part listener in `org.eclipse.ui.internal.BaseSaveAction` is not being fired. How are you opening the editor?

Comment: @greg-449 I'm opening the editor by making a command. Check the code

Comment: @greg-449 CallEditor class is used to open editor.

Answer (score 1):

Call

```
firePropertyChange(PROP_DIRTY);
```

to mark the editor part as dirty.

Your editor's `isDirty()` method will be called at various points to check the dirty state.

Comment: I did but it does not work. When I get into fireProperty change while debugging I found the list of listeners empty and it return from there. No listener is called further.

Comment: This is the standard mechanism used by all editors. You better show us some code.